# TomEE | JNDI - javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory Resource Creation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, apache-tomee

Okay, so I am very hopeful that this is possible. Many libraries offer implementations of `javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory` ([MongoDB](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/jndi/), [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JNDI-DataSource-Factory-(Tomcat,-etc.))). I am trying to take these examples, aimed at Tomcat, and code them in TomEE's `resources.xml`.

TomEE veteran Romain has a [fantastic explanation](https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/openejbtomee-resources-how-does-it-work/) on how the `resources.xml` works. Unfortunately, without a provider for `javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory`, creating a custom datasource is quite difficult for this interface.

I am hoping a TomEE dev can chime in on the possibility of `javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory`'s in `resources.xml`, or the possibility of it in another TomEE configuration file, or perhaps a future feature if this is not currently possible.